# can we use loop functions in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Can we use loop functions(for,while,do while) in tableau calculated Fields? If we can, how can we use the these functions in calculated fields and how can we initialise the variables which are declared in these functions?

Answer (score 4):

No we can't. There are some hacks to do some calculations like that, using PREVIOUS_VALUE and other table calculations, but there is no loop functions in Tableau.

Why? Because Tableau isn't meant to be a data processing tool, but rather a data visualization tool. Don't get me wrong, Tableau engine is very good to process data, but only to perform "query-like" operations.

So why don't you post exactly what you are trying to achieve and we can think if it's possible to be accomplished with Tableau, or you require some pre-processing in your data

Comment: Hi Inox. I have something that might need the use of loops, not sure. Here is the issue: https://community.tableau.com/thread/317048 Any help is appreciated.